# why completed tasks on spark worker node much less than master node?

Tags: apache-spark

I have double node spark cluster:
master : 8gb 8 cores
worker: 8gb 4 cores
I increased executor memory to 3g and I want to balance the load between master and worker but the master still get most of the load and master node ram get around 98% but not worker node
[image]

Comment: You need to supply some code for us to see - surely?